# How to split D to calculate $\int_Df(x,y)d(x,y)$ for $f(x,y)=xe^{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let
$$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 1\le x^2+y^2 \le 4 ,\quad y\ge0\}$$
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$f(x,y)=xe^{x^2+y^2}$$

Calculate $\int_Df(x,y)d(x,y)$

I believe the order of integration must be $dxdy$. However, I can't clearly express $x$ as a function of $y$. What is the correct way to split the set $D$ so we can integrate?

Comment: You'll probably be better off using polar coordinates

Comment: Also, $f$ maps $R^2$ to $R$, not to $R^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using polar coordinates you have:
$x=r\cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$. Where $r \geq 0, t \in \mathbb{R}$
Now looking at points in D we realize that,because $x^2+y^2=r^2$, we must have that 
$$
1 \leq r^2 \leq 4
$$
Moreover $y\geq 0$ means that $t \in [0,\pi]$.

Now under a change of variables in the intergration we need to calculate the Jacobian  which turns out to be $r$ (exercise).

Thus the integration over $D$ becomes: 
$$
\int_0^\pi\int_1^2r^2 \cos(t)e^{r^2} drdt
$$
Which is a lot simpler.
Can you finish from here?

Comment: you're missing the Jacobian term here

Comment: @NL1992 thanks, edited.

Comment: If I understood correctly that is the determinant of the jacobian because we are chaining $f$ and the polar coordinate switch?

Comment: I can solve that integral, but how do we change the integration order without expressing one variable as the other? (I have only ever seen it done like this, a pointer would be much appreciated!)

Comment: Isn't the first integral from 1 to 4? You have also written the two integrals as drdt.

Comment: @Axion004 $r^2; r \geq 0$, ranges from 1 to 4 so $r$ ranges from 1 to 2.

Comment: @RubenKruepper could you give an example of an integral done in the manner you wish to do?

Comment: @Matthew your edit cleared it up for me, I was confused because of $\int_{1}^{2} dt$ not $dr$, while $r$, not $t$ ranges from 1 to 2. :)

Comment: @Matthew, you said it is a lot simpler, could you please expand your solution? The $r^2$ is killing me when integrating...

Comment: @RubenKruepper it involves the error function so may not be so simple if you haven't seen that. https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint%20x%5E%7B2%7De%5E%7Bx%5E2%7Ddx

Comment: @RubenKruepper also see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html